# Getting empty data object from my form react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Form is **returning empty data object**, but it should return values typed in form.
onSubmit function should console.log values given in form, but I don't know why it does not working.
Please check it out.

```
function App() {
    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(data);
        console.log('sent');
    };
    const onError = (errors, e) => console.log(errors, e);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}>
                    <input
                        name="email"
                        autoComplete="off"
                        placeholder="Your email"
                        ref={register({ name: "email" }, { required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i })}
                        
                    />
                    <select
                        defaultValue="default"
                        name="select1"
                        ref={register({ name: "select1" }, { required: true })}
                    >
                        <option value="default" disabled>default</option>
                        <option value="A">A</option>
                        <option value="B">B</option>
                    </select>
                    <textarea
                        name="message"
                        placeholder="Your message"
                        ref={register({ name: "message" }, { required: true })}
                    />
                    <button type="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your render function with `register` method:

`register` only need validation argument within input elements.

API reference: https://react-hook-form.com/api#register

and also a section for get started:

https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Quickstart

```
return (
    <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}>
                <input
                    name="email"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    placeholder="Your email"
                    ref={register({ required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i })}
                    
                />
                <select
                    name="select1"
                    ref={register({ required: true })}
                >
                    <option value="" disabled>default</option> // make sure this is empty to get validation work.
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                </select>
                <textarea
                    name="message"
                    placeholder="Your message"
                    ref={register({ required: true })}
                />
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </header>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: now i have a two questions why i'm not getting validation required on select? and i'm confused because when i add defaultValue to select it's not returning this data after i delete it, it return data, but i wanted to create isssue and tested it on codesandbox template it works fine.

Comment: because <option value="default" disabled>default</option> this is always going to have a value, you should leave as ""

Comment: also you fill up your form with useForm({ defaultValues }) as well

Answer (score 0):

generally that's not how things are done in react you need a formData state object which will have same field as your form and n each form input you'll have an onchange function which updates the appropriate formData field like this

```
function App() {
    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
    const [formdata, setformdata] = useState({
          message:"",
          email:"",
          choice:"",
    });
    const onSubmit = ( e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //your form data now is in formdata
        console.log(formdata);
        console.log('sent');
    };
    const onError = (errors, e) => console.log(errors, e);
    const onChangeHandler= (field)=>(e)=>setformdata({...formdata,[field]:e.target.data})
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}>
                    <input
                        name="email"
                        onChange={onchangeHandler('email')}
                        autoComplete="off"
                        placeholder="Your email"
                        ref={register({ name: "email" }, { required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i })}
                        
                    />
                    <select
                        defaultValue="default"
                        name="select1"
                        onChange={onchangeHandler('choice')}
                        ref={register({ name: "select1" }, { required: true })}
                    >
                        <option value="default" disabled>default</option>
                        <option value="A">A</option>
                        <option value="B">B</option>
                    </select>
                    <textarea
                        name="message"
                        placeholder="Your message"
                        onChange={onchangeHandler('message')}
                        ref={register({ name: "message" }, { required: true })}
                    />
                    <button type="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I fixed typo onchangehandler to onChangeHandler, but setformdata is not a function

Comment: ohh sorry my bad the state varaible should've been ```[formdata, setformdata] ``` but instead mistakenly  and wrote ``` {formdata, setformdata}``` , just fix that typo and try again .

Comment: i tried it again and i'm formdata values are undefinded ;//

Comment: When you get `undefinded` check version useForm.

You could write example code from v7 but installed v6

Comment: The problem here , when a form has a lot of fields , the form becomes so slow , as with each character hit u will update the whole form state.